# I am working on a simple BlackJack web app and I would like to replace specific strings with specific images using either JS or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

I have been working on a simple Javascript web app and now that I have it working functionally I would like to replace the card text with images. For example, the players hand is stored in an array and I am using document.getElementById to show the text (C10, D7, HK, etc.) of those cards within the html.   I would like to replace the text with their corresponding images. I can't do it by tag id as the id will be the same for all the cards. I think I probably need a jQuery loop that checks the strings within the tag and replaces the cards with their image file...

I tried the below but this only work for one card at a time.

```
function jQ (){
  $("#img").html($("#img").html().replace(new RegExp("\\b"+"C5"+"\\b"), "<img src=C5.png>"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the image filename is the same as the card name, you can use a back-reference in the replacement string.

```
$("#img").html(function(i, oldhtml) {
    return oldhtml.replace(/[CHDS][1-9AKQJ]/, "<img src='$&.png'>");
});
```

`$&` gets the part of the string that matched the regexp.

Comment: Thank you, that is much neater than what I had been trying to go with!